# How to point different js and css files in each Laravel environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two environments, development and production.

In master.blade layout file, I point to my local js file like that:

```
<script src="http://192.168.2.40/js/jscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I convert this line to the following one for production server.

```
<script src="http://s.mysite/js/jscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is very annoyting and error-prone to switch between them. How can I solve this problem in an environment independent way.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hardcode your addresses.

In your `.env` file add a new record:

```
//.. env stuff
APP_URL=http://192.168.2.40 //or http://s.mysite on your production server
```

Then in your `config/app.php` if you don't already have it, add a declaration for your `url`:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

Comment: How would I use `'url'` function in blade, and is a new variable, `APP_STATIC_URL`, more suitable?

Comment: @user2356198 You would call it like this -> `config('app.url')`. And `suitable` would be up to you.